# jQuery addClass to visible elements with delay

Tags: jquery

I want to add a class to each element that is currently in the window, with a delay between for a domino effect.

What I have does the delay just fine but adds the class to all matched elements and not just the ones in view.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').each(function(i){
    if($(this).scrollTop() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
      var tile = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        tile.addClass('visible');
      }, 500*i);
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `delay` in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to be checking for the `scrollTop` of the box. You want to be checking for the `offset().top`

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').each(function(i){
    if($(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
      var tile = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        tile.addClass('visible');
      }, 500*i);
    };
  });
});
```